# Swift 3 : How to sequential process download files and open ViewController

Tags: ios, swift3, nsurlsession

I want to click a button, then download a number of files sequentially and after complete download, then open a webview to display. But I encounter download files not completed the webview already opened. I saw some approach in days and don't know how to fix the problem. Can anyone help?

Many Thanks.

DownloadManager Class

```
class DownloadManager: NSObject {

    /// Dictionary of operations, keyed by the `taskIdentifier` of the `URLSessionTask`

    fileprivate var operations = [Int: DownloadOperation]()

    /// Serial NSOperationQueue for downloads

    private let queue: OperationQueue = {
        let _queue = OperationQueue()
        _queue.name = "download"
        _queue.maxConcurrentOperationCount = 1    // I'd usually use values like 3 or 4 for performance reasons, but OP asked about downloading one at a time

        return _queue
    }()

    /// Delegate-based NSURLSession for DownloadManager

    lazy var session: URLSession = {
        let configuration = URLSessionConfiguration.default
        return URLSession(configuration: configuration, delegate: self, delegateQueue: nil)
    }()

    /// Add download
    ///
    /// - parameter URL:  The URL of the file to be downloaded
    ///
    /// - returns:        The DownloadOperation of the operation that was queued

    @discardableResult
    func addDownload(_ url: URL) -> DownloadOperation {
        let operation = DownloadOperation(session: session, url: url)
        operations[operation.task.taskIdentifier] = operation
        queue.addOperation(operation)
        return operation
    }

    /// Cancel all queued operations

    func cancelAll() {
        queue.cancelAllOperations()
    }

}

// MARK: URLSessionDownloadDelegate methods

extension DownloadManager: URLSessionDownloadDelegate {

    func urlSession(_ session: URLSession, downloadTask: URLSessionDownloadTask, didFinishDownloadingTo location: URL) {
        operations[downloadTask.taskIdentifier]?.urlSession(session, downloadTask: downloadTask, didFinishDownloadingTo: location)
    }

    func urlSession(_ session: URLSession, downloadTask: URLSessionDownloadTask, didWriteData bytesWritten: Int64, totalBytesWritten: Int64, totalBytesExpectedToWrite: Int64) {
        operations[downloadTask.taskIdentifier]?.urlSession(session, downloadTask: downloadTask, didWriteData: bytesWritten, totalBytesWritten: totalBytesWritten, totalBytesExpectedToWrite: totalBytesExpectedToWrite)
    }
}

// MARK: URLSessionTaskDelegate methods

extension DownloadManager: URLSessionTaskDelegate {

    func urlSession(_ session: URLSession, task: URLSessionTask, didCompleteWithError error: Error?)  {
        let key = task.taskIdentifier
        operations[key]?.urlSession(session, task: task, didCompleteWithError: error)
        operations.removeValue(forKey: key)
    }

}

/// Asynchronous Operation subclass for downloading

class DownloadOperation : AsynchronousOperation {
    let task: URLSessionTask

    init(session: URLSession, url: URL) {
        task = session.downloadTask(with: url)
        super.init()
    }

    override func cancel() {
        task.cancel()
        super.cancel()
    }

    override func main() {
        task.resume()
    }
}

// MARK: NSURLSessionDownloadDelegate methods

extension DownloadOperation: URLSessionDownloadDelegate {

    func urlSession(_ session: URLSession, downloadTask: URLSessionDownloadTask, didFinishDownloadingTo location: URL) {
        do {
            let manager = FileManager.default
            let destinationURL = try manager.url(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask, appropriateFor: nil, create: false)
                .appendingPathComponent(downloadTask.originalRequest!.url!.lastPathComponent)
            if manager.fileExists(atPath: destinationURL.path) {
                try manager.removeItem(at: destinationURL)
            }
            try manager.moveItem(at: location, to: destinationURL)
        } catch {
            print("\(error)")
        }
    }

    func urlSession(_ session: URLSession, downloadTask: URLSessionDownloadTask, didWriteData bytesWritten: Int64, totalBytesWritten: Int64, totalBytesExpectedToWrite: Int64) {
        let progress = Double(totalBytesWritten) / Double(totalBytesExpectedToWrite)
        print("\(downloadTask.originalRequest!.url!.absoluteString) \(progress)")
    }
}

// MARK: NSURLSessionTaskDelegate methods

extension DownloadOperation: URLSessionTaskDelegate {

    func urlSession(_ session: URLSession, task: URLSessionTask, didCompleteWithError error: Error?)  {
        completeOperation()
        if error != nil {
            print("\(error)")
        }
    }

}

/// Asynchronous operation base class
///
/// This is abstract to class performs all of the necessary KVN of `isFinished` and
/// `isExecuting` for a concurrent `Operation` subclass. You can subclass this and
/// implement asynchronous operations. All you must do is:
///
/// - override `main()` with the tasks that initiate the asynchronous task;
///
/// - call `completeOperation()` function when the asynchronous task is done;
///
/// - optionally, periodically check `self.cancelled` status, performing any clean-up
///   necessary and then ensuring that `completeOperation()` is called; or
///   override `cancel` method, calling `super.cancel()` and then cleaning-up
///   and ensuring `completeOperation()` is called.

public class AsynchronousOperation : Operation {

    override public var isAsynchronous: Bool { return true }

    private let stateLock = NSLock()

    private var _executing: Bool = false
    override private(set) public var isExecuting: Bool {
        get {
            return stateLock.withCriticalScope { _executing }
        }
        set {
            willChangeValue(forKey: "isExecuting")
            stateLock.withCriticalScope { _executing = newValue }
            didChangeValue(forKey: "isExecuting")
        }
    }

    private var _finished: Bool = false
    override private(set) public var isFinished: Bool {
        get {
            return stateLock.withCriticalScope { _finished }
        }
        set {
            willChangeValue(forKey: "isFinished")
            stateLock.withCriticalScope { _finished = newValue }
            didChangeValue(forKey: "isFinished")
        }
    }

    /// Complete the operation
    ///
    /// This will result in the appropriate KVN of isFinished and isExecuting

    public func completeOperation() {
        if isExecuting {
            isExecuting = false
        }

        if !isFinished {
            isFinished = true
        }
    }

    override public func start() {
        if isCancelled {
            isFinished = true
            return
        }

        isExecuting = true

        main()
    }
}

/*
 Copyright (C) 2015 Apple Inc. All Rights Reserved.
 See LICENSE.txt for this sample’s licensing information

 Abstract:
 An extension to `NSLock` to simplify executing critical code.

 From Advanced NSOperations sample code in WWDC 2015 https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2015/226/
 From https://developer.apple.com/sample-code/wwdc/2015/downloads/Advanced-NSOperations.zip
 */

extension NSLock {

    /// Perform closure within lock.
    ///
    /// An extension to `NSLock` to simplify executing critical code.
    ///
    /// - parameter block: The closure to be performed.

    func withCriticalScope<T>(block: () -> T) -> T {
        lock()
        let value = block()
        unlock()
        return value
    }
}
```

Then, I call below code when click download button.

```
func downloadFiles() {

    do {

        var localJson: JSON?
        let serverJson = self.serverJson
        let str = serverJson?.description
        let data = str?.data(using: .utf8)

        let fileManager = FileManager.default
        let documentsUrl = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first! as URL

        let oldManifestUrl = documentsUrl.appendingPathComponent("manifest.json")
        let oldManifestPath = oldManifestUrl.path


        if fileManager.fileExists(atPath: oldManifestPath) {

            let jsonData = NSData(contentsOfFile:oldManifestPath)
            localJson = JSON(data: jsonData! as Data)
        }


        var totalCount = 0

        let downloadManager = DownloadManager()


        for (index, subJson): (String, JSON) in serverJson! {

            for (_, subJson): (String, JSON) in subJson {
                let filepath = subJson["path"].stringValue
                let nUpdated = subJson["updated"].stringValue

                if let oUpdated = localJson?[index].array?.filter({ $0["path"].string == filepath}).first?["updated"].stringValue {
                    if (oUpdated == nUpdated) { continue }
                }


                var absPath = filepath

                let strIdx = absPath.index(absPath.startIndex, offsetBy: 2)


                if (absPath.hasPrefix("./"))
                {
                    absPath = absPath.substring(from: strIdx)
                }


                let sourceUrl = URL(string: self.sourceUrl.appending(absPath))

                downloadManager.addDownload(sourceUrl!)


            }

        }

        // Remove temp json file first if exists.
        if fileManager.fileExists(atPath: oldManifestPath) {
            try? fileManager.removeItem(atPath: oldManifestPath)
        }

        // Write temp json file to local.
        try data?.write(to: oldManifestUrl)

        self.defaults.set(hashes, forKey: "LastHash")

        let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Information", message: "Download completed", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.alert)
        alertController.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: UIAlertActionStyle.default, handler: nil))
        self.present(alertController, animated: true, completion: {

            self.openWebView()


        })

    } catch {
        print("Write JSON data to file failed, \(error.localizedDescription)")
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

What you need is a promise library that offers code execution on certain completion conditions. Currently, you make the request and open the webview straight away. The requests take time to load but your code doesn't tell the device to wait for the requests to finish before opening up the webview. You can use [PromiseKit](https://github.com/mxcl/PromiseKit) for this purpose. With this library, you can send multiple requests asynchronously and then open the webview when all of the requests have been processed. You will have to explore it in order to understand how it works. Basically, your code structure will look something like this

```
var promiseArray = [Promise<Void>]()
for WHATEVER CONDITION YOU WANT TO USE FOR THE LOOP {
    let promise = YOUR REQUEST GOES HERE
    promiseArray.append(promise)
}
_ = when(fulfilled: promiseArray).then {
    OPEN WEBVIEW HERE
}
```